# k8s cronjob not running updated codes, but manual create this job works

Tags: python, kubernetes, cron, yaml, containers

I have a cronjob running in k8s and inside a specific container. I have a python script to run in this cronjob, however it didn't run the latest codes, but I've checked the images it pulled was the latest.

When I **manually** run ***kubectl create job --from=....***, it did run the latest python codes.

Am I missing something?

I've already tried to delete the existed cronjob and apply it again, it still not running the latest codes. It runs the latest codes only when I manually create job.

Quite strange behavior between auto and manually run the same job....

Describe job - cronjob auto run

```
Name:           severity-1637733600
Namespace:      security
Selector:       controller-uid=167b250b-831c-4725-a1f8-bb46553e2948
Labels:         controller-uid=167b250b-831c-4725-a1f8-bb46553e2948
                job-name=severity-1637733600
Annotations:    <none>
Controlled By:  CronJob/severity
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Wed, 24 Nov 2021 14:00:00 +0800
Completed At:   Wed, 24 Nov 2021 14:00:51 +0800
Duration:       51s
Pods Statuses:  0 Running / 1 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  controller-uid=167b250b-831c-4725-a1f8-bb46553e2948
           job-name=severity-1637733600
  Containers:
   fetch-y-info:
    Image:      security/portal:3c62acai
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
    Args:
      -c
      python scripts/severity.py -vv
    Environment:
      DB_DRIVER:    <set to the key 'driver' in secret 'security-secret'>    Optional: false
    Mounts:         <none>
  Volumes:          <none>
Events:             <none>
```

Describe job - manual run

```
Name:           severity-manual
Namespace:      security
Selector:       controller-uid=97952b85-24a5-4bbc-8e49-247e8bf2dcb1
Labels:         controller-uid=97952b85-24a5-4bbc-8e49-247e8bf2dcb1
                job-name=severity-manual
Annotations:    cronjob.kubernetes.io/instantiate: manual
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Wed, 24 Nov 2021 15:34:56 +0800
Completed At:   Wed, 24 Nov 2021 15:35:18 +0800
Duration:       22s
Pods Statuses:  0 Running / 1 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  controller-uid=97952b85-24a5-4bbc-8e49-247e8bf2dcb1
           job-name=severity-manual
  Containers:
   fetch-y-info:
    Image:      security/portal:3c62acai
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
    Args:
      -c
      python scripts/severity.py -vv
    Environment:
      DB_DRIVER:    <set to the key 'driver' in secret 'security-secret'>    Optional: false
    Mounts:         <none>
  Volumes:          <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From            Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  2m7s  job-controller  Created pod: severity-manual-hbtzd
  Normal  Completed         105s  job-controller  Job completed
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: There's no error. It's just not running my latest codes....

Comment: In that case you need to post the CronJob yaml to the question, and `kubectl describe` the completed job (run manually vs k8s scheduled).

Comment: I've posted the describe, thanks

Comment: The CronJob runs 51s while the manual job runs 22s. If they did same thing with same set of data, how do you tell which is the "latest code", are you looking at some sort of output, eg. logs? table? Can you briefly (no need great details) describe what's the different between the two that make you believe one of them is not up to date and how many worker nodes in your cluster?

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of reasons. Check if both jobs (the ones manually created and the ones created by the cronjob) are using the same image ID: (Assuming there is only one container in your pod)

`kubectl get job <job-name> -o=jsonpath='{.spec.template.spec.containers[0].image}'`

If they both match, it could be two different images with the same tag, which are already present on different nodes in your cluster. This relates to the [image pull policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#image-pull-policy) specified on the cronjob. You can check if this is the case by changing the image ID in your cronjob to an image digest.

> To make sure the Pod always uses the same version of a container image, you can specify the image's digest; replace : with @ (for example, image@sha256:45b23dee08af5e43a7fea6c4cf9c25ccf269ee113168c19722f87876677c5cb2).